# How to merge an Object and non-object-valued in HOCON?

Tags: scala, hocon

I am using HOCON configuration in my project. But I am stuck with Configuring a Hive connection.

The HOCON doc says:

> The JSON spec does not clarify how duplicate keys in the same object
>   should be handled. In HOCON, duplicate keys that appear later override
>   those that appear earlier, unless both values are objects. If both
>   values are objects, then the objects are merged.

Now having these two configurations how can I make this HOCO read them both?

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true; 
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
```

Answer (score 3):

Hive configuration options like `hive.exec.dynamic.partition` are just names containing `.`, not paths, so in HOCON they need to be quoted:

```
"hive.exec.dynamic.partition" = true
"hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode" = nonstrict
```

Alternately, define your own HOCON config structure and translate it into Hive configuration options as you want. E.g. you could say if there's anything under `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode`, `hive.exec.dynamic.partition` is automatically `true`.